# Installing dependencies of specific packages from another package.json

Tags: npm

I have an npm project which is used solely for UI components and I have another one that is used for everything else. Since these two will be running in the same environment, I want to make sure they use the exact same version of runtime dependencies.

Here's an example. The project structure looks like:

```
root
- UI Component Project
- Main Project
```

The "Main Project" has a package.json with all the necessary dependencies it needs. What I want to do is to let "UI Component Project" use the exact same versions of the dependencies used in "Main Project", but only those that are also used in "UI Component Project".

For example, "Main Project" may have several dependencies such as TypeScript, React, and several others. "UI Component Project" also has its own set of runtime dependencies but they also use TypeScript and React. In this case, I want to make sure "UI Component Project" installs its own dependencies plus TypeScript and React with the same exact version used in "Main Project".

Does npm natively support something like this? I'm looking for something automatic to achieve this without manually trying to sync the dependencies in two projects.

Answer (score 0):

I found that tools like lernacan help me do this.